# How many simultaneous RYNC sessions can be started at once

Tags: rsync

Just wanted to know that if Rsync is doing backup and in my cron job other rsync session times comes . Can both run simultaneously or first has to be completed before second starts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are using the same *source and different destinations* on the directory structure I would not do this unless they are both using a source which is guaranteed not to change (unlikely).  Instead, you probably want to use `flock` to create a lock file for the process in this case. You can then either kill the current and replace with new, or stop the newer one from running.  You probably want the second option or else if they are not timed right the rsync operation may never get to the end.

If the source is guaranteed not to change and they are different destinations, this might even be good because it might take advantage of file caches.

If they use sources and different destinations, you can run them at the same time with no problem.  However, I would carefully watch `iostat` to make sure you don't overload your IO.

So In Summary if your goal is to have two directory trees synced up:

- Same Source / Different Destination = Okay, but only if static source, else unpredictable due to race conditions. The two destinations might not be in sync with each other.
- Same Source / Same Destination = Doubt it is okay, but I see no possible advantage.  Use a lock file.
- Different Source / Same Destination =  Results will depend on race conditions.  You probably would want to coordinate the sources some how. Maybe use the `--update` flag.
- Different Source / Different Destination = Perfectly fine, but watch IO load.

You might be able to solve some of the race condition problems using the `--update` flag:

> This  forces  rsync  to  skip any
>   files which exist on the destination
>   and have a modified time that is newer
>   than the source file.

Delete options and changing directory structures could complicate these even further I think.

Answer (score 1):

If it's running on separate parts of your filesystem, I don't see a reason why you should be limited in any way.

If you're doing several rsync over the same part of your filesystem (say, the same folder), they may interfere with each other.